# C++ open window hello world

Tags: c++, window

How can you write a **C++** program to open a **window** like this one...
[image]

Is it possible or can apps only be ran from the **command line**?

I'm using the **G++** compiler... Do I need something else like visual studio?

Can I do it just by writing code?

Comment: What IDE/Code editor are you using to perform this?

Comment: Its a very broad question, there are a number of libraries that can be used to do that e.g. Qt http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29, WTL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTL and MFC that comes with visual studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) which is a cross-platform framework that easily builds GUIs.

Then check out a Qt tutorial, do a google search. [Here is one](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Beginners) that will get you to "hello world"

Also, you might want to check out [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) as an IDE. It will use your already installed g++ compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Borland C++, Visual C++ they has GUI or wxWindow or GTK library.

Answer (score 2):

The best and most low-level way of doing this would be by using the Windows API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows

Microsoft itself provides excellent tutorials and documentation on how to program with their Windows Application Programming Interface, but there are also numerous other tutorials out there that can be found quickly with a google search.

To create a window like the one you ask about in the question, you would be looking for the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program

It might seem daunting at first, but the Windows API is extensive and provides a huge amount of functionality, on top of just creating GUIs. It would probably be worthwhile familiarising yourself with it if you are interested in Windows programming.

Answer (score 1):

Search for WinApi Tutorials like this [one](http://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/)

there are alot
or you can also you the Visual Studio MFC application wizard and create a dialog application

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides a tuturial for doing that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx

Answer (score 1):

GUI programming requires the use of additional libraries. There is a C++ GUI library supplied by Microsoft for Windows called MFC. There are many other GUI libraries out there.

If you use these GUI libraries, you don't need to run the application from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Windows api from within C++.